# Do I have to make constructors for all inherited classes in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

My base class has a constructor with parameters (String, String, int)
Three different classes inherit from it.
Inherited class A has a constructor with parameters (String, String, int) too but with different implementation.

My question is if I do not make a constructor in inherited classes B and C with parameters (String, String, int) will they inherit the base class' constructor ?
I need the same implementation in B and C as in the base class.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: what do you understand by the word constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a constructor in base class `B` and `C`, you will get the default constructor. This is a no parameter constructor provided by the runtime, and you can use it for any `Object` without an explicit `constructor` defined.

If you want to access a superclass constructor, you can do something like.

```
public A(String str, String str2, int num)
{
    super(str, str2, num);
}
```

**Extra Reading**

- You can read about the use of the `super` keyword [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).
- You can read about what get's inherited in Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: Actually super was exactly what I was looking for at that thime

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no, the constructors are not inherited. You'll have to redefine them in every subclass.

The exception to this is the implicit parameterless constructor that calls the parameterless constructor of the superclass, which is present if no other constructor is explicitly defined.